# Why cookie is not stored though reverse proxy is used?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, reverse-proxy

This below is the response header after a *login*. Frontend runs on port 3000, backend 8080. Why am I not able to see `vapor-session` under Cookie tab after this response? Secure or HTTPOnly is not used, so it should be visible.

```
set-cookie: vapor-session=MVUx69HNqLcJyZGml+qBWwoE6BKcgLfk8XHGSdfyos8=; Expires=Sun, 16 Oct 2022 15:46:34 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
```

Yes, this is the final step in OAuth 2.0 sequence, FE -> BE -> Github -> BE -> Github -> BE -> FE.

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: accept, authorization, content-type, origin, x-requested-with, user-agent, access-control-allow-origin, crossdomain, access-control-allow-credentials, x-requested-with
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
access-control-allow-origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
access-control-max-age: 600
connection: close
content-length: 681
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 09 Oct 2022 16:33:16 GMT
set-cookie: vapor-session=RVNKuaxQ0JFBoaO7gOiVJsmMQo0hjJr+oTb97ypANZk=; Expires=Sun, 16 Oct 2022 16:33:16 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: origin, Accept-Encoding
```

reverse proxy is set in `next.config.js`:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/api2/:path*',
            destination: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/:path*`,
        },
    ]
},
```

When I start Next.js I see this:

> $ next dev
> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

- Can it be that app starts on "localhost" but somehow it will be redirected to "127.0.0.1"?
- Can "0.0.0.0:3000" interfere maybe?

Comment: Yes, `localhost` is a hostname that resolves to the ip address `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Ahh ok, somehow it redirects from `localhost` to 127.0.0.1, so this is the root of problem.